# how to map this array if i want to the Names of the groups listed in different "quesytion"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, map-function

How can I get the names of different activity in an array by using map function in this type of response. So that in a new array, assume that `activity[] i` will get names of all the activities mention below.
if the array is

```
 const response = [
       {
           "Groups" : {
               "Roles" : {
                   "submission": {
                       "subject" : {
                           "name": "history",
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ];
```

Comment: can you tell us what you have tried ?

Comment: Actually I don't know so I was going by this approach .
and i dont know what to write in function??


function* checkPermission() {
    let activity = [];
    Roles.map(Permission.map(Activity.map(function () {
        }

    )));
    activity.push(activity[i].name);
}

Comment: Can You provide an output of that example above? What should be in the activity array?

Comment: in activity array it should be like this  activity["Manage Users", "Manage Clients"]  like this

Comment: Which properties are static? Will your response always consist of an array with one object with the property Roles.Permission ? Or do you have to detect those keys as well? Will there be more than one Roles object?

Comment: there can be more than one roles too and in one activity there can be multiple activities

Comment: How you wanna collect your activities? Do you wanna collect activity names in each record only for current object? Or you wanna colllect all activities names from all objects?

Comment: collect all activities names from all objects(Permisson1,Permission2,Permisson3, etc) like this

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using an [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) but there may be cleaner ways

assuming there in one object in the array and no other path to other permission

```js
const response = [
  {
    "Roles" : {
      "Permission" : {
        "PERMISSION1": {
          "Activity" : {
            "name": "Manage Clients",
          }
        },
        "PERMISSION2": {
          "Activity" : {
            "name": "Manage Users",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

let activities = (() => {
  let res = []
  for (let perm in response[0].Roles.Permission) {
    for (let act in response[0].Roles.Permission[perm]) {
      res.push(response[0].Roles.Permission[perm][act].name)
    }
  } 
  return res})()
  
console.log(activities)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should convert `Permission` object to array, cause object doesn't have method map.

Then you could use `map` function where you can collect all your permissions' names for every item in response

```js
const response = [{
  "Roles": {
    "Permission": {
      "PERMISSION1": {
        "Activity": {
          "name": "Manage Clients",
        }
      },
      "PERMISSION2": {
        "Activity": {
          "name": "Manage Users",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}];

response.forEach((item) => {
  item.Activities = Object.values(item.Roles.Permission).map((permission) => permission.Activity.name)
});

alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

The only array you have is response. If each item in response has a Roles that has a Permission that has several keys with objects that have Activity with name then you can do the following:

```js
var response = [
    {
        Roles: {
            Permission: {
                PERMISSION1: {
                    Activity: {
                        name: 'Manage Clients',
                    },
                },
                PERMISSION2: {
                    Activity: {
                        name: 'Manage Users',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
];
console.log(
  response.map(
    (item) => 
      Object.values(item.Roles.Permission)
      .map(
        (permission) => permission.Activity.name
      )
    )  
);
```

Comment: then in console.log we will get the different names of the activities which are mentioned right?

Comment: @Anonjohn Yes, but not unique for the "Roles" key. If your data is more dynamic you should provide more sample data and if the activity names have to be unique then I can add that to the code.

Comment: no there are different activities which are assigned to different permissions and that permissions can be assigned to different groups of people. now you understand?

Comment: @Anonjohn no, you should supply an example that shows your situation instead of trying to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a flatMap, so use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const response = [{
  "Roles": {
    "Permission": {
      "PERMISSION1": {
        "Activity": {
          "name": "Manage Clients",
        }
      },
      "PERMISSION2": {
        "Activity": {
          "name": "Manage Users",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}];

const activityNames = response.reduce(function (acc, res) {
  const permissions = res.Roles.Permission;
  const permissionKeys = Object.keys(permissions);
  const names = permissionKeys.map(function(permissionKey) {
    return permissions[permissionKey].Activity.name;
  });
  acc.push(...names);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(activityNames); // ["Manage Clients", "Manage Users"]
```

Comment: there can be multiple roles with multiple permissions and multiple activities